# Sum of null columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table where A, B and C allow null values.

```
SELECT  
   A, B, C, 
   A + B + C AS 'SUM' 
FROM Table
```

If my `A, B and C` values are `10, NULL and NULL`, my `SUM` column shows nothing in it.

Is there any way to fix this, and display `SUM` as 10? OTHER THAN converting *NULL* s to Zeros?

Comment: No. you will have to convert NULL to zero.

Comment: Convert `NULL` to zero ***IS*** the solution ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use SQL  [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) which uses the value in the column, or an alternative value if the column is null

So

```
SUM ( COALESCE(A,0) + COALESCE(B,0) + COALESCE(C,0))
```

Comment: @MitchWheat Not in the database it isn't.

Comment: Neither marc or I were ever suggesting converting the actual data!

Comment: @MitchWheat Well, sorry, but I didn't know how to get my query to calculate the sum. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use `IsNull(Column, 0)` to ensure it is always 0 at minimum.

```
SELECT  
   A, B, C, 
   IsNull(A,0) + IsNull(B,0) + IsNull(C,0) AS 'SUM' 
FROM Table
```

`ISNULL()` determines what to do when you have a null value. if column returns a null value so you specified a 0 to be returned instead.