# How do I sum values from one table by account numbers in another table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm a beginner/intermediate user of Python and I'm now trying to build a accounting program in order to learn more about databases and how they interract.

I currently have three different sqlite3 tables: ListOfAccounts, GeneralLedger and EventLedger.

- ListOfAccounts contains 6 columns named account_nr, account_name, account_type, debit, credit and balance.
- GeneralLedger contains 3 columns named entry_id (Primary key), entry_date and description.
- EventLedger contains 5 columns named primary_id (Primary key), entry_id (foreign key which relates to GeneralLedger), account_nr, debit and credit.

When you enter a new transaction there's one entry in GeneralLedger and then multiple entries in EventLedger related to the entry in the GeneralLedger which disperse the amount transacted between different accounts.

Now to my problem. In the debit and credit columns in ListOfAccounts, I want to sum the transactions in EventLedger by account_nr and no matter what I try I can't seem to get it to work.

If it doesn't result in an Error then the credit and debit columns in ListOfAccounts is still 0 (zero).

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

The closest I've gotten to a solution is the code below. Although this just returned 0.0 in the ListOfAccounts table.

```sql
SELECT L.account_name, SUM(E.debit) AS Balance
FROM EventLedger E 
JOIN ListOfAccounts L ON L.account_nr = E.account_nr_E
GROUP BY L.account_name
```

ListOfAccounts columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
ListOfAccounts(
account_nr INTEGER,
account_name TEXT,
account_type TEXT,
debit REAL NOT NULL, 
credit REAL NOT NULL,
balance REAL NOT NULL);
```

EventLedger columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
EventLedger(
primary_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
entry_id INTEGER,
account_nr_E INTEGER,
debit REAL,
credit REAL);
```

What I want to happen is as follows:

EventLedger contains multiple entries.

| primary_id | entry_id | account_nr_E | debit | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1001 |  | 5000 |
| 2 | 1 | 4001 | 5000 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 1001 |  | 550 |
| 4 | 2 | 5001 | 550 |  |
| 5 | 3 | 1001 | 15000 |  |
| 6 | 3 | 3010 |  | 15000 |

ListOfAccounts contains sum of the accounts in EventLedger.

| account_nr | account_name | account_type | debit | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Checking acc. | asset | 15000 | 5550 |
| 3010 | Sales | income |  | 15000 |
| 4001 | Car exp. | cost | 5000 |  |
| 5001 | Utility | cost | 550 |  |

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23309577/5320906) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query which I can see is that you are grouping by `L.account_name`, but you are summing `E.debit`. It means that you get the total debit for all accounts with the same name. However, if you would like to get the total debit for each account, you need to group by `E.account_nr_E`.

Updated sql query:

```
SELECT L.account_name, SUM(E.debit) AS Balance
FROM EventLedger E
JOIN ListOfAccounts L 
ON L.account_nr = E.account_nr_E
GROUP BY E.account_nr_E
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but unfortunately this did not solve the issue. The debit column in ListOfAccounts still doesn't sum the values.